# Using variable on php to create another variable in JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database

I'm having a hard time getting the value of a specific variable in php to use in js. This is my code in php:

```
<?php
require("connection.php");

$sql_cmd = "SELECT * FROM tbstatus";

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql_cmd);
$stmt->execute();

echo "<h2>STATUS OF THE BABY</h2>";

while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<h4>" . $result['status'] . "</h4>";
}
?>
```

I want to get the value of this ($result['status']) and pass it on the variable pos in js. This is my js code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#position").load('refresh.php');
    notif();

}, 1000);

function notif() {
    var pos = $('PHP VARIABLE HERE').val();
    alert(pos);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you try `echo` for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to output it to javascript directly:

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.MY_PHP_VAR = <?php echo json_encode($myPhpVar); ?>;
</script>
...

window.MY_PHP_VAR now contains your php variable
```

Answer (score 1):

if your javascript code is on same page where the result is comming then you can use this

```
var pos =  `<?php echo $result['status'] ?>`;

var pos =  `<?= $result['status'] ?>`;
```

Answer (score -1):

1. you could try giving an id or class to the **status**.
2. then in JavaScript you could then get the value of the id or class.

#### PHP

```
<?php
require("connection.php");

$sql_cmd = "SELECT * FROM tbstatus";

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql_cmd);
$stmt->execute();

echo "<h2>STATUS OF THE BABY</h2>";
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<h4> <span class="status">' . $result['status'] . '</span></h4>';
}

?>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var oldStatus = '';

setInterval(function() {
    $("#position").load('refresh.php');
    notif();
}, 1000);

function notif() {
    // note that since we used a class, you will get the value of the first element only.
    var pos = $('.status').text(); // use .text() instead of .val()
    if (pos.toLowerCase() == 'out' && pos != oldStatus){
        oldStatus = pos;
        alert(pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working now. Thank You. But I have a little bit concern. Since I have setInterval in my js, every second it will alert me with the value of status. I want is to just alert me once, if the value of the status does not change. Is it possible? Thank you

Comment: replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout`

Comment: If I use setTimeout, it will not automatically refresh my web. I needed that to get the latest value from my database

Comment: i've modified my answer. check it out.

Comment: I don't understand this. I want it to notify me when the status is "Out".

Comment: i've modified my answer. check it out.

Answer (score -1):

```
===============
// refresh.php
===============

<?php  
require("connection.php");
$sql_cmd = "SELECT * FROM tbstatus";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql_cmd);
$stmt->execute();

echo "<h2>STATUS OF THE BABY</h2>";

while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo "<h4>" . $result['status'] . "</h4>";
      echo "<script> alert('". $result['status'] ."'); </script>";
      /* If the $result['status'] is 'success' the above line will be converted to:
       echo "<script> alert('success'); </script>";
      */
}

?>
```

so, every time the refresh.php loads, the script is going to get executed.

However, I suggest you to assign a id or class attribute to your h4 where you are echoing your status and access the value using the selectors in the javascript.